# Expose a web service (wsdl) as a webform

Tags: java, web-services, webforms, wsdl, enunciate

Just wanted to ask if anyone knows of a **reliable & easy way to expose a webservice (wsdl) as a webform** to end-users.

Our team develops a lot of software for external contacts, which often involve creating a web service and exposing it as both a wsdl and a website. We'd like to automate this last step as much as possible (especially for the mindless data-pumping projects) so we can concentrate on developing web services instead of websites.

I recently came across Enunciate, <strike>but have not found the time yet to play with it in detail</strike>. I was wondering if anyone has any experience with it  (or with any similar projects) what your findings are, and what direction you would advice us to take with this.

Best regards,
Tim

---

**Update2**:
Turns out what I need is perfectly described in this Enunciate module: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE-23. The only problem is that it's not implemented... (yet?)
Anyone have any experience in creating your own modules, or knows of an existing solution that provides the same functionality?

Comment: This looks somehwat like what I intended.. Anyone know of any alternatives aswell? http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how much weight my response carries (since I'm the lead developer of Enunciate) but I'd like to encourage you to try it out. I know a lot of happy Enunciate users.

Even if you decide not to use it, I'd like to hear about your experience and why you decided against it.

Comment: Thanks for replying here.. I'm going to try a bit harder again, this time using Ant instead of Maven. Turns out the maven archetype returns a different codebase from the enunciate download package, so I'm trying again with that aswell.. (So far I've been able to compile, will let you know what comes up next..)

Comment: @Ryan: I've been looking into Enunciate again, and it turns out that what I need is a HTML form module as described in this issue: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE-23 However, the latest update on that issue seems to be from April last year.. Is this something we can still expect in the future?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using the Metro libraries to provide the web service engine, a web page is produced when accessing the end point with a GET which allows you to easily get the WSDL if you need it.

I do not know if that is what you mean with a "web site" but it is a nice default way to work.